# Does CURLOPT_POST need to have the number of postfields or just 1/true?

Tags: php, post, curl

I've seen `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);` mostly written in this way but have noticed that some people express the `count()` number of post fields instead of `1`/`true`. Why might they be doing this or could it simply be a misunderstanding of the option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_POST.html):

> A parameter set to 1 tells libcurl to do a regular HTTP post. This will also make the library use a "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" header. (This is by far the most commonly used POST method).

Seems to me like it's a boolean. The content-type is enforced for POST requests to be sent properly, which are already default that way in HTML forms that use POST, but not in cURL requests - they have to be set up for it (so this flag is the equivalent of `method="post"` or `method="get"` depending on which value you give it, `>=1` or `0` respectively.

The reason you saw `count($data)` in this field in some places is to (in my assumption) disable `POST` when the `$data` is empty dynamically, so it's `0` when it is empty and `>=1` otherwise.

Comment: The answer to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4526273/what-does-enctype-multipart-form-data-mean) question seems to imply that the default is already `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` so I still can't see how this option has any impact on the request?

Comment: Because that's referring to HTML forms, not a cURL request. cURL requests would be plain GET by default, and this setting turns it into a POST request. The reason you saw `count($data)` in this field in some places is to maybe disable POST when the `$data` is empty, so it's 0 when it is empty and >=1 otherwise.